# A true cross-platform handwriting app

Tags: notes, crossplatform, annotation, vector-drawings

`MS OneNote` is nice, but its snap counterpart on Ubuntu is kind of meh. [Xournal++](https://xournalpp.github.io/) is awesome and has now a [mobile version](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp_mobile). Except, so far it's just beta and drawing gets jerky after a couple of lines already.

Is there a notes taking app which would be available on Windows, Linux and Android?

My typical scenario: I want to draw stuff on my tablet and then open it one desktop and be able to edit it.

Xournal++ would be ideal if its mobile version wasn't so jerky. I can draw with it on my tablet and then open the `xopp` file on the desktop and edit it. I don't care about sync, I just want to be able to open a file created on the tablet on my PC and vice versa. Xournal++ does that, the only con is that it's mobile version is too beta.

Comment: Xournal++ works in Windows and Mac too.

Comment: I don't expect any application designed for a desktop to be good for mobile and vice versa.  For cross platform note taking you don't really need the same application, you just need a common place to save your notes, like a cloud provider either self-hosted or commercial.  If you want the application to include your cloud storage you're not so much looking for an application as you are a **service**. Personally, I usually take notes in markdown and use Markor on Android and Typora for desktop, selfhosted on OwnCloud

Comment: @Nmath See the description of my case in the updated question

Comment: Oh *those* kinds of notes... Sorry I don't have any idea of a cross platform app. The implementation/development of drawing apps is radically different between apps designed for a mobile touchscreen vs ones designed for desktop peripherals like a mouse and drawing tablet.  You'd also still need some kind of service to sync the files from one device to another

Comment: Theory is the same though.  You might be better off with different applications while using a file type that can be opened and edited by both your choice of mobile application and your choice of desktop application.

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I don't know how it's called precisely, but anyhow I don't care about sync. 

Well ... there is no such file type!

Comment: *"I don't care about sync"* - you'd have to have some kind of sync or you would not be able to open the same notes on different devices.  Again, I'm not sure what applications would be able to handle the same files between desktop and mobile, but there would be some kind of file type for the notes

Comment: @Nmath I'm telling you, Xournal does this -- you can easily check it out yourself. If you draw smth on your phone, say, you can save it and then open on in your desktop Xournal and it will all be editable.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify if you need the app to include a service or if you plan to manually transfer files between devices.  If xournal allows you to work on one device and continue working on the same notes on another device, there must be a technical reason for how the data is transferred or shared between devices -- if you want the same usability then any other application you use would also need to be able to do this.  I am pointing out that you would either need the app to have this feature or you would need to find another way to sync data.

Comment: @Nmath Just stop fixating on the data transfer. Yes, I'm fine with transferring the files manually. I only need to be able to open and edit them on my desktop AND tablet